# Python: How to repeat the last input prompt before wrong input?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have an for statement which prompts the user to input 5. numbers. Like this:

```
"Input 1. number:

input 2. number:

..
..
.."
```

I want to repeat the last prompt the user gets before he makes a wrong input (number too big).
But  my program skips the wrong one:

like this

```
"Input 1. number:
5
Accepted

input 2. number:
999
Wrong! Retry
(here I use *continue* for the loop)

input 3.number:

---"
```

What should I do to re-ask the second question?

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 5):

By using `continue` you are probably continuing ahead to the next input number. Try something like this:

```
number_of_inputs = 10
max_input = 99
for i in range(number_of_inputs):
    answer = 0
    while not answer or answer > max_input:
        try:
             answer = int(raw_input('Input {}. number: '.format(i)))
        except ValueError:
             continue
    print 'The user selected', answer, 'for input', i
```